# Bulk IP configuration using CSV input

Tags: powershell, csv, ip, jobs, bulk

I have a CSV file with the following values for each machine I want to remotely reconfigure using static IP

```
name,nic,ip,mask,defaultgw
```

I was hoping to be able to reconfigure the IPs for each listed but if I have more than one machine listed the script gets stuck. This is because at the end of the first loop iteration, unless I manually do an `ipconfig /flushdns` on the server the script is running from, I will lose connection to the server being configured and the script just hangs leaving the rest of the servers. What I have so far is this:

```
$csv = import-csv "c:\scripts\builds\machines.csv"

foreach ($Row in $csv) {
    $machine = $Row.name
    $Nic = $row.Nic
    $address = $row.IP
    $mask =$row.mask
    $defaultgw = $row.gw

    invoke-command -computername $machine -scriptblock { Get-NetIpAddress - InterfaceAlias $using:nic | New-NetIPAddress -ipaddress $using:address -PrefixLength $using:mask -DefaultGateway $using:defaultgw | Register-DnsClient}}
}
```

Can this be done using workflows or just simple start-job?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance.  What is $using?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're losing the connection to the remote machine once you change the IP address, while the local machine hangs trying to keep the connection.

Try making the call, and dropping off a payload, then running it **after you disconnect**.

That is, upload the code, then spawn it, then disconnect before it has a chance to run (add a sleep to the remote code maybe?). This way, you can launch your payload and disconnect before it affects you.

For example, you could copy a file to that machine with the values it needs, then schedule a task to run in 5 seconds in the future, then disconnect before it runs.  The task will then run, and since you're already disconnected, you won't be affected by it.

You might also consider DHCP with static reservations.  It's far easier to manage than what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Hi as part of the build process it gets a DHCP temporarily anyway. The purpose of my question is that we have to change that address to a static one we set aside for permanent purposes, so DHCP is not an option. What you have mentioned below "For example, you could copy a file to that machine with the values it needs, then schedule a task to run in 5 seconds in the future, then disconnect before" it runs is a good idea but how can I code that when making reference to a csv file with multiple server name entries?? The csv file needs to remain on a share