# Reading a CSV file in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am creating a Powershell script. My CSV file looks like below:

```
ServerName,IPAddress,SubnetMask,MACAddress
Server01,10.0.0.1,255.0.0.0,00:00:00:00:00:01
Server02,10.0.0.2,255.0.0.0,00:00:00:00:00:02
Server03,10.0.0.3,255.0.0.0,00:00:00:00:00:03
```

I have tried below command on single server and then successfully assigned IP address and subnetmask. I am stuck when querying all the servers by their corresponding MAC from CSV file. I want to loop it to each server and corresponding MAC then assign IP address and subnet mask.

Can I do it via CSV, or is there any other way to do it?

```
$nic = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName server01 | 
    Where-Object { $_.MACAddress -eq "00:00:00:00:00:01" }
    $nic.EnableStatic($IPAddress,SubnetMask)
```

Comment: Thanks to below link. I understood the csv concept from this link and used wmi to change the IP on multiple servers from my csv:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55126976/bulk-ip-configuration-using-csv-input

Answer (score 0):

```
$FileContent=@"
ServerName,IPAddress,SubnetMask,MACAddress
Server01,10.0.0.1,255.0.0.0,00:00:00:00:00:01
Server02,10.0.0.2,255.0.0.0,00:00:00:00:00:02
Server03,10.0.0.3,255.0.0.0,00:00:00:00:00:03
"@
#
# You can either export the text to a file and import it as csv
$FileContent | Out-File test.csv
$AllServers = Import-Csv test.csv -Delimiter ","
#
# You can also convert the text straight to csv
$AllServers = @()
$AllServers = $FileContent | ConvertFrom-csv -Delimiter ","
foreach ($Server in $AllServers)
  {
    $nic = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Server.ServerName | Where-Object { $_.MACAddress -eq "$($Server.MACAddress)"}
    Write-Host "$($Server.ServerName): $($nic.Description) will be assigned $($Server.IPAddress) and $($Server.SubnetMask)"
    #$nic.EnableStatic($Server.IPAddress,$Server.SubnetMask)
  }
```

I would also go for *New-NetIPAddress* as suggested in [Bulk IP configuration using CSV input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55126976/bulk-ip-configuration-using-csv-input)